# Add break line at certain position

Tags: ruby, string, format

How do I format `str`:

```
str = "2013-12-03 10:19:06 +0100: Success: 34 => ["reset/htx", "auth/mx", "auth/htx", "product", "product/id", "product/id/review", "search/offer", "search/ac", "location", "location/zone", "shop", "shop/id", "shop/id/category", "shop/id/contact", "shop/id/terms", "shop/id/return", "shop/id/oid/fragment", "retailer", "retailer/id", "user/id/account", "user/id/review", "user/id/review/id", "user/id/product", "user/id/product/id", "user/id/tag", "category", "category/urlName", "about", "about/terms", "about/privacy", "about/order", "about/order/state", "about/tp", "about/tp/abbrev"]"
```

To get this output:

```
2013-12-03 10:19:06 +0100: Success: 25 => ["reset/htx", "auth/mx", "auth/htx", "product", "product/id", "product/id/review", 
                                           "search/offer", "search/ac", "location", "location/zone", "shop", "shop/id", 
                                           "shop/id/category", "shop/id/contact", "shop/id/terms", "shop/id/return", 
                                           "shop/id/oid/fragment", "retailer", "retailer/id", "user/id/account", 
                                           "user/id/review", "user/id/review/id", "user/id/product", "user/id/product/id"]
```

At first I just tried to add break lines but with

```
x.scan(/.{100}/).join("\n")
```

break lines are added between words. I also tried using

```
str.split("").each_slice
```

but it also didn't work.

Comment: Why does "Success: 34" change to "Success: 25"? Is it important to the question that you provide such a long sample input string? Couldn't you reduce it to something *much* shorter and still ask the same question? "[ask]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, there's probably not a simple solution for this. Here's some code you could work with.

```
str = %q{2013-12-03 10:19:06 +0100: Success: 34 => ["reset/htx", "auth/mx", "auth/htx", "product", "product/id", "product/id/review", "search/offer", "search/ac", "location", "location/zone", "shop", "shop/id", "shop/id/category", "shop/id/contact", "shop/id/terms", "shop/id/return", "shop/id/oid/fragment", "retailer", "retailer/id", "user/id/account", "user/id/review", "user/id/review/id", "user/id/product", "user/id/product/id", "user/id/tag", "category", "category/urlName", "about", "about/terms", "about/privacy", "about/order", "about/order/state", "about/tp", "about/tp/abbrev"]}

max_length = 100
timestamp, list = str.split(' => [')
result = ''
line = timestamp += ' => ['
list.split(' ').each do |item|
  if line.length + item.length > max_length
    result += line + "\n"
    line = ' ' * timestamp.length
  end
  line += item
end
result += line

puts result
```

Which returns:

```
2013-12-03 10:19:06 +0100: Success: 34 => ["reset/htx","auth/mx","auth/htx","product","product/id",
                                           "product/id/review","search/offer","search/ac",
                                           "location","location/zone","shop","shop/id",
                                           "shop/id/category","shop/id/contact","shop/id/terms",
                                           "shop/id/return","shop/id/oid/fragment","retailer",
                                           "retailer/id","user/id/account","user/id/review",
                                           "user/id/review/id","user/id/product",
                                           "user/id/product/id","user/id/tag","category",
                                           "category/urlName","about","about/terms","about/privacy",
                                           "about/order","about/order/state","about/tp",
                                           "about/tp/abbrev"]
```

Please note, however, that you would run into trouble if any single list item were too long for `max_length`. In the above case, the indent is 43 characters and the `max_length` 100. A single list item longer than 57 charactes would though have to be broken and would cause the above code to produce overflow lines.